# How to make a custom HTML error other than error 404?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do you create a custom error page like error 503 Service Unavailable, 403 Forbidden, 204 No Content?

I've tried using 404_override with route setting and it works, so I wonder if it can use for the other errors?

Comment: You can also do this at the web server level if necessary. That helps if your app is so broken it can't even render errors.

Comment: but is it possible to create one through CI?
I mean, HTML error configuration is web server jobs, but could we do it using code in CI?

Comment: Your CodeIgniter app can handle most of them, but not all. You'll want a fail-safe one at the web server level anyway.

Comment: well thanks that's what I want to know